# Does $P({X_1}^->a_1,...,{X_n}^->a_n)\leq P({X_1}^+>a_1,...,{X_n}^+>a_n)\forall a$ imply $E[h({X_1}^-,...,{X_n}^-)]\leq E[h({X_1}^+,...,{X_n}^+)]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let ${X_1}^-,...,{X_n}^-,{X_1}^+,...,{X_n}^+$ be real random variables with the following stochastic dominance property:

$P({X_1}^->a_1,...,{X_n}^->a_n)\leq P({X_1}^+>a_1,...,{X_n}^+>a_n)$ for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$.

Now let $h:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ be strictly increasing in every component.

Does then

$E[h({X_1}^-,...,{X_n}^-)]\leq E[h({X_1}^+,...,{X_n}^+)]$ hold?

Ideas: Using the definition of expectation brought me to a sub-problem that I asked here: [In an inequality of integrals, can I multiply both integrands with the same non-negative, monotonous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908382/in-an-inequality-of-integrals-can-i-multiply-both-integrands-with-the-same-non)
However, maybe that was already a step in the wrong direction, thus here the original problem.

Thanks in advance!